# Get the set of numbers in a list whose sum matches the required number given

Tags: python-3.x, list, set

I am currently working on a problem -the statement is like

I am given an list of numbers and A number-s. I need to find out the collection(s) of numbers from the list of numbers whose sum corresponds to the given number s.

Now I can do this using nested for loops or even `itertools.combinations()` -BUT both of them have big time complexities..

Can anyone please help me what should be my approach or what algorithm should I use to have a clean and simple code to achieve it in better time complexity?